# Visual Studio/C# Issues with .Checked Boxes In User Settings

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

So I'm dabbling in C# properly for the first time trying to make a WPF based desktop application.

So far it's mostly going well, however as part of the project I am trying to take input from the user in one window (essentially where they define a project and the settings they want) and save them for later user in the project and have it act accordingly based on their input.

I've figured out the saving of this data for text inputs etc, however I'm having issues replicating this for check boxes.

I've defined the setting in the settings page as a bool defaulting to false, with the intent to be if the user ticks the checkbox then set the setting to true for later use.

When I'm trying to use .Checked against my checkbox class name it says it must appear on the left hand side of of += or -=, I've looked online for clarification and most similar code & relevant tutorials define it the way I have without issue.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```cs
public void CXML_GetSettings()
        {
            CXML_NewProject_Inc_SubModule_XML.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CXML_Project_Inc_SubModule;

        }
```

Tried various ways of changing it but just can't get .Checked to work anywhere.

Comment: Welcome Casey! Can you provide a full example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken it's not any complex code, just any attempt to use .Checked doesn't seem to behave the way other sources suggest it should.

But for clarify here is the little bit of code a window currently has:

https://pastebin.com/yfGyB6sn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Checked is an event for CheckBox, if you want to use it for your CheckBox, you can use it like below:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyCheckBox.Checked += MyCheckBox_Checked;
    }

    private void MyCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Or

```
    <CheckBox IsChecked="False" Name="MyCheckBox" Checked="MyCheckBox_Checked"/>

    private void MyCheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, C# handles .Checked in a very odd way :)